# For Loop Not Working in a Laravel Controller Class

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, laravel-5

In my Laravel project, I have a BusController.php file where I need to run a for() loop. However, the loop is not working. I also tried a blade for looping but have the same problem.

**BusController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Bus;
use App\Bus_type;
use App\Company;
use App\Http\Requests;

class BusController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $buses = Bus::all();
        $bus_types = Bus_type::all();
        $companies = Company::all();

        return view('admin.adding_bus', compact('buses', 'bus_types', 'companies'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $bus = new Bus;
        $bus->company_name = $request->company_name;
        $bus->bus_type = $request->bus_type;
        $bus->bus_number = $request->bus_number;
        $bus->no_of_rows = $request->no_of_rows;
        $bus->no_of_columns = $request->no_of_columns;
        $seats = "";

        for ($i = 1; $i <= ($request->no_of_rows * $request->no_of_columns); $i++) {
            $seats = $seats . "b";
        }
        $bus->seats = $seats;

        $bus->save();
        $buses = Bus::all();
        $bus_types = Bus_type::all();
        $companies = Company::all();

        return view('admin.adding_bus', compact('buses', 'bus_types', 'companies'));
    }
}
```

Comment: try after remove braces like for($i = 1; $i <= $request->no_of_rows * $request->no_of_columns; $i++){
        $seats = $seats."b";
    }

Comment: Can you dump values of `$request->no_of_rows` and `$request->no_of_columns` before `for` cycle?

Comment: i want to have a string which has $request->no_of_rows * $request->no_of_columns b in seats string. Actually i am tring to do seats += "b"; @SagarGuhe

Comment: I tried this @ManinderpreetSingh but this message is given Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Comment: ok then try with for($i = 1; $i <= (int)$request->no_of_rows * (int)$request->no_of_columns; $i++){ $seats = $seats."b"; }

Comment: $seats = "";
  $totalSeats = $request->no_of_rows * $request->no_of_columns;

  for($i = 1; $i <= $totalSeats; $i++){
   $seats = $seats."b";
  }
  I tried this but result is same @alexander.polomodov

Comment: just add result of `var_dump($request->no_of_rows, $request->no_of_columns);` as comment below and we will help you with your for loop. We just need some debug info

Comment: Actually input validation problem is the cause of error. Thanks all problem solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have validated the data you received from the `Request`. Because if you don't the loop will be fail since the `loop condition` will always be false.
And to test it, here's what I do:

```
$seats = "";
$num_cols = 2;
$num_rows = ''; // assume you don't validate the request, so this can receive empty string too
// $num_rows = 0; // will output the same as above
for($i = 1;$i<=($num_cols * $num_rows);$i++)
{
    $seats = $seats."b";
}
var_dump($seats);
```

Output:

```
string(0) ""
```

And here it is working one:

```
$seats = "";
$num_cols = 2;
$num_rows = 20; // correctly validated as integer and must be more than 0 because you're doing multiplication here in the following loop
for($i = 1;$i<=($num_cols * $num_rows);$i++)
{
    $seats = $seats."b";
}
var_dump($seats);
```

Output:

```
string(40) "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
```